# Convert string containing roman numerals to numeric using R

Tags: r, number-formatting, numeric, roman-numerals

I want to convert "stage i", "stage ii", etc to numeric "1" and "2".

```
pheno_df$pathologic_stage <- gsub("stage ","",pheno_df$pathologic_stage)
as.numeric(factor(pheno_df$pathologic_stage))
```

Current output:

```
3 2 3 3 2 5
```

Desired output:

```
2 1 2 2 1 4
```

Data sample:

```
> dput(pheno_df$pathologic_stage)
c("stage ii", "stage i", "stage ii", "stage ii", "stage i", "stage iv",
```

Answer (score 3):

Extract the numeral part, then convert to `roman` and back to `numeric`:

```r
v <- c("stage ii", "stage i", "stage ii", "stage ii", "stage i", "stage iv")
as.numeric(as.roman(gsub("stage ", "", v)))
#[1] 2 1 2 2 1 4
```